# My auto correct form is showing zero on value

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I try and click the external bead to change the value it just says zero, also when I unselect the values it won't zero

https://codepen.io/callum-edwards/pen/oNvBWxo

I have tried and can't manage to get this to work I'm sure its because its not being able to go back and get the value of price
I've been trying for a while now

```js
$(function() {
  $(function() {
    var fields = $(
      "select[name=bead],select[name=cpu],select[name=GPU]"
    ).change(calculate);

    function calculate() {
      var price = 0;
      fields.each(function() {
        price += +$(this).val();
      });
      $("#price").html(price.toFixed(2));
      if (price === 0) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 0 bags of plaster Costing £0.00");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "0.00");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 0.00);
      }
      if (price >= 10) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 1 bags of plaster Costing £6.23");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "6.23");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 6.23);
      }
      if (price >= 20) {
        $("#test").html("You  would need 1 bags of plaster Costing £66.23");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "6.23");

        $("#plaster").html(price + 6.23);
      }
      if (price == 30) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 1 bags of plaster Costing £6.23");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "6.23");

        $("#plaster").html(((price + 6.23) * 100) / 100);
      }

      if (price >= 40) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 2 bags of plaster Costing £1f2.46");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "12.46");

        $("#plaster").html(price + 12.46);
      }

      if (price >= 50) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 2 bags of plaster Costing £12.46");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "12.46");

        $("#plaster").html(price + 12.46);
      }
      if (price >= 60) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 2 bags of plaster Costing £12.46");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "12.46");

        $("#plaster").html(price + 12.46);
      }
      if (price >= 70) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 3 bags of plaster Costing £18.69");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "18.69");

        $("#plaster").html(price + 18.69);
      }
      if (price >= 80) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 3 bags of plaster Costing £18.69");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "18.69");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 18.69);
      }
      if (price >= 90) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 3 bags of plaster Costing £18.69");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "18.69");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 18.69);
      }
      if (price >= 100) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 4 bags of plaster costing £24.92");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "24.92");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 24.92);
      }
      if (price >= 110) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 4 bags of plaster costing £24.92");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "24.92");

        $("#plaster").html(price + 24.92);
      }
      if (price >= 120) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 4 bags of plaster costing £24.92");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "24.92");

        $("#plaster").html(price + 24.92);
      }
      if (price >= 130) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 5 bags of plaster costing £31.15");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "31.15");

        $("#plaster").html(price + 31.15);
      }
      if (price >= 140) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 5 bags of plaster costing £31.15");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "31.15");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 31.15);
      }
      if (price >= 150) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 5 bags of plaster costing £31.15");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "31.15");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 31.15);
      }
      if (price >= 160) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 6 bags of plaster costing £37.38");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "37.38");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 37.38);
      }
      if (price >= 170) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 6 bags of plaster costing £37.38");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "37.38");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 37.38);
      }
      if (price >= 180) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 6 bags of plaster costing £37.38");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "37.38");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 37.38);
      }

      if (price >= 190) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 7 bags of plaster costing £43.61");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "43.61");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 43.61);
      }

      if (price >= 200) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 7 bags of plaster costing £43.61");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "43.61");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 43.61);
      }
      if (price >= 210) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 7 bags of plaster costing £43.61");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "43.61");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 43.61);
      }
      if (price >= 220) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 7 bags of plaster costing £43.61");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "49.84");
        $("#plaster").html(49.84 + price);
        $("#test").html("You would need 8 bags of plaster costing £49.84");

      }
      if (price >= 230) {
        $("#plaster").html(price + 49.84);
        $("#test").html("You would need 8 bags of plaster costing £49.84");

      }
      if (price >= 240) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 8 bags of plaster costing £49.84");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "49.84");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 49.84);
      }
      if (price >= 250) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 9 bags of plaster costing £57.06");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "57.06");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 57.06);
      }
      if (price >= 260) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 9 bags of plaster costing £57.06");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "57.06");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 57.06);
      }
      if (price >= 270) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 9 bags of plaster costing £57.06");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "57.06");
        $("#plaster").html(((price + 57.06) * 100) / 100);
      }
      if (price >= 280) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 10 bags of plaster costing £62.30");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "62.30");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 62.3);
      }
      if (price >= 290) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 10 bags of plaster costing £62.30");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "62.30");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 62.3);
      }
      if (price >= 300) {
        $("#test").html("You would  need 10 bags of plaster costing £62.30");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "62.30");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 62.3);
      }
      let p = $("#plaster")
      p.html(Math.round(+p.html() * 1000) / 1000)
    }
  });
});

//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function() {
  if (animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  next_fs = $(this)
    .parent()
    .next();

  //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
  $("#progressbar li")
    .eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs))
    .addClass("active");

  //show the next fieldset
  next_fs.show();
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
      scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
      left = now * 50 + "%";
      //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({
        transform: "scale(" + scale + ")",
        position: "absolute"
      });
      next_fs.css({
        left: left,
        opacity: opacity
      });
    },
    duration: 800,
    complete: function() {
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    },
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: "easeInOutBack"
  });
});

$(".previous").click(function() {
  if (animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  previous_fs = $(this)
    .parent()
    .prev();

  //de-activate current step on progressbar
  $("#progressbar li")
    .eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs))
    .removeClass("active");

  //show the previous fieldset
  previous_fs.show();
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
      scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
      left = (1 - now) * 50 + "%";
      //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({
        left: left
      });
      previous_fs.css({
        transform: "scale(" + scale + ")",
        opacity: opacity
      });
    },
    duration: 800,
    complete: function() {
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    },
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: "easeInOutBack"
  });
});

$(".submit").click(function() {
  return false;
});
```

```css
/*custom font*/

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  /*Image only BG fallback*/
  /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
}

body {
  font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}


/*form styles*/

#msform {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#msform fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
  /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
  position: relative;
}


/*Hide all except first fieldset*/

#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}


/*inputs*/

#msform select,
#msform input,
#msform textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: montserrat;
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-size: 13px;
}


/*buttons*/

#msform .action-button {
  width: 100px;
  background: #27AE60;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}

#msform .action-button:hover,
#msform .action-button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}


/*headings*/

.fs-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2C3E50;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.fs-subtitle {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/*progressbar*/

#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
  counter-reset: step;
}

#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #333;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}


/*progressbar connectors*/

#progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 9px;
  z-index: -1;
  /*put it behind the numbers*/
}

#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  /*connector not needed before the first step*/
  content: none;
}


/*marking active/completed steps green*/


/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/

#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
  background: #27AE60;
  color: white;
}

#msform .ms-field-title {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>

<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform">
  <!-- progressbar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
    <li>Social Profiles</li>
    <li>Personal Details</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Crreate your account</h2>
    Labour:
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">£<u name="plaster" id="plaster"></u></h3><input hidden type="text" id="ouch" />
    <select name="cpu" id="CPU">
      <option value="0" selected>Width</option>
      <option value="10">2ft</option>
      <option value="20">4ft</option>
      <option value="30">6ft</option>
      <option value="40">8ft</option>
      <option value="50">10ft</option>
      <option value="60">12ft</option>
      <option value="70">14ft</option>
      <option value="80">16ft</option>
      <option value="90">18ft</option>
      <option value="100">20ft</option>
      <option value="110">22ft</option>
      <option value="120">24ft</option>
      <option value="130">26ft</option>
      <option value="140">28ft</option>
      <option value="150">30ft</option>
    </select>
    </span>
    <select name="GPU" id="GPU">
      <option value="0" selected>Length</option>
      <option value="10">2ft</option>
      <option value="20">4ft</option>
      <option value="30">6ft</option>
      <option value="40">8ft</option>
      <option value="50">10ft</option>
      <option value="60">12ft</option>
      <option value="70">14ft</option>
      <option value="80">16ft</option>
      <option value="90">18ft</option>
      <option value="100">20ft</option>
      <option value="110">22ft</option>
      <option value="120">24ft</option>
      <option value="130">26ft</option>
      <option value="140">28ft</option>
      <option value="150">30ft</option>
    </select>
    <select name="bead" id="bead">
      <option value="0" selected>External Corners</option>
      <option value="2.25">1</option>
      <option value="11.11">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <span style="text-align:left;" id="test" class="ms-field-title"><sup>*</sup></span>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
    <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
    <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
    <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
    <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I have tried all I know but I'm fairly new to this

I would like the external corner to output a value also the form to change value when unselected.

Comment: i had to update the codepen link and the code as it was wrong

Comment: no need to wrap document ready in a document ready `$(function() {`

Comment: To add on to @MarkSchultheiss's comment, the event handlers *should* be wrapped in document ready, so you can remove one of them, and extend the other to wrap all of your code.

Comment: @callum Hi, can you edit your question adding a little bit more detail about the issue? I still can't complain what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not very simple, has hard coded values and a few issues.

First simplify and DRY the code - I created a name space (`myApp`) for stuff to avoid global variables which is generally bad. I then moved the data into a data object and out of the complex if/else if/else you had set up and simplified that to a simple call using that data. Note now `pricesRanges` now holds the range where the values change so is easier to maintain and also not embedded in the code so you can add adjust and remove ranges without changing the logic as it now uses the `lookUpMatch` function to find that.

I adjusted the animations to simplify and made one out of both of them.  To simplify this I set data attributes for the target using for example `targetindex="1"`, to facilitate that, I added a class so that if you change the markup from a `fieldset` to something else it still works using `field-group`.

```js
var myApp = myApp || {
  pricesRanges: [{
    range: 0,
    bags: 0
  }, {
    range: 10,
    bags: 1
  }, {
    range: 40,
    bags: 2
  }, {
    range: 70,
    bags: 3
  }, {
    range: 80,
    bags: 3
  }, {
    range: 100,
    bags: 4
  }, {
    range: 130,
    bags: 5
  }, {
    range: 160,
    bags: 6
  }, {
    range: 190,
    bags: 7
  }, {
    range: 220,
    bags: 8
  }, {
    range: 250,
    bags: 9
  }, {
    range: 280,
    bags: 10
  }, {
    range: 290,
    bags: 10
  }, {
    range: 390,
    bags: 10
  }],
  basePrice: 6.23,
  maxRange: 390,
  animating: false,

  // set during processing
  fields: undefined,
  current_fs: undefined,
  next_fs: undefined,
  previous_fs: undefined,
  left: undefined,
  opacity: undefined,
  scale: undefined,
  // functions
  lookUpMatch: function(arr, val, prop) {
    let found = arr.find(function(el) {
      return el[prop] >= val;
    });
    if (!found) {
      return "notfound";
    } else {
      if (prop in found) {
        return found;
      } else {
        return "No such property";
      }
    }
  },
  nextPrev: function() {
    if (myApp.animating || $(this).is('.is-disabled')) {
      return false;
    }
    let targetIndex = $(this).data("targetindex");
    let isPrev = $(this).is('.previous');

    myApp.current_fs = $(this).closest('.field-group');
    myApp.next_fs = myApp.current_fs.next('.field-group');
    myApp.previous_fs = myApp.current_fs.prev('.field-group');

    let fs_CurrIndex = myApp.current_fs.index('.field-group');
    let fs_PrevIndex = myApp.previous_fs.index('.field-group');
    let fs_NextIndex = myApp.next_fs.index('.field-group');

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index
    let pb = $("#progressbar").find("li");
    pb.eq(targetIndex).toggleClass("active", true);
    pb.eq(fs_CurrIndex).toggleClass("active", !isPrev);

    let targets = $('.field-group');
    targets.eq(targetIndex).css('opacity', 1).show();

    //hide the current field-group with style
    myApp.animateHideCurrent(myApp.current_fs);
  },
  animateHideCurrent: function(fsTarget) {
    myApp.animating = true;
    myApp.current_fs.animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, {
      step: function(now, mx) {
        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
        //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
        myApp.scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
        //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
        myApp.left = now * 50 + "%";
        //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
        myApp.opacity = 1 - now;
        myApp.current_fs.css({
          transform: "scale(" + myApp.scale + ")",
          position: "absolute"
        });
        myApp.next_fs.css({
          left: myApp.left,
          opacity: myApp.opacity
        });
      },
      duration: 800,
      complete: function() {
        fsTarget.hide();
        myApp.animating = false;
      }
      // comment out as not in this example
      //this comes from the custom easing plugin
      // ,easing: "easeInOutBack"
    });
  },

  calculate: function() {
    let $price = $("#price");
    let $test = $("#test");
    let $plaster = $("#plaster");
    let $ouch = $("#ouch");
    let testText = "";
    let plasterCost = 0;
    // I just went with the name pattern used
    let ouchValue = 0;
    let bags = 0;
    let price = 0;
    let hasAllValues = true;
    myApp.fields.each(function() {
      // validate if length and width both selected by ignore of Corners
      if ($(this).val() == 0 && !$(this).is('#bead')) {
        hasAllValues = false;
      }
      price = price + ($(this).val() * 1);
    });
    // disable "Next" until both width and length selected
    let thisNext = $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.next');
    thisNext
      .prop('disabled', hasAllValues ? '' : 'disabled');
    thisNext.toggleClass('is-disabled', !hasAllValues);

    $price.html(price.toFixed(2));
    if (price >= myApp.maxRange) {
      // what to do here?
      //  console.log("price exceeds max:", price, myApp.maxRange);
    } else {
      let x = myApp.lookUpMatch(myApp.pricesRanges, price, "range");
      ouchValue = x.bags * myApp.basePrice;
      bags = x.bags;
      plasterCost = price + ouchValue;
    }
    $ouch.val(ouchValue);
    // interpolated string
    testText = `You would need ${bags} bags of plaster Costing £${ouchValue.toFixed(2)}`;
    $test.html(testText);
    $plaster.html(Math.round(plasterCost * 1000) / 1000)
  }
};

/*
// test some ranges:
// maxRange just allows us to put a fixed point in.
let ranges = [0, 10, 12, 50, 136, 200, 290, 333, 400];
ranges.forEach(function(range) {
  if (range >= myApp.maxRange) {
    console.log("range exceeds max:", range, myApp.maxRange);
  } else {
    let x = myApp.lookUpMatch(myApp.pricesRanges, range, "range");
    console.log("x", x, range);
  }
});
*/


$(function() {
  // this could be a class also
  myApp.fields = $("#CPU,#bead,#GPU").on('change', myApp.calculate);
  $(".next").on('click', myApp.nextPrev);
  $(".previous").on('click', myApp.nextPrev)
  $(".submit").on('click submit', function() {
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
/*custom font*/

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  /*Image only BG fallback*/
  /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
}

body {
  font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}


/*form styles*/

#msform {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#msform fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
  /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
  position: relative;
}


/*Hide all except first fieldset*/

#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}


/*inputs*/

#msform select,
#msform input,
#msform button,
#msform textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: montserrat;
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-size: 13px;
}


/*buttons*/

#msform .action-button {
  width: 100px;
  background: #27AE60;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}

#msform .action-button.is-disabled {
  background: #dddddd;
}

#msform .action-button:hover,
#msform .action-button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}


/*headings*/

.fs-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2C3E50;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.fs-subtitle {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/*progressbar*/

#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
  counter-reset: step;
}

#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #333;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}


/*progressbar connectors*/

#progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 9px;
  z-index: -1;
  /*put it behind the numbers*/
}

#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  /*connector not needed before the first step*/
  content: none;
}


/*marking active/completed steps green*/


/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/

#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
  background: #27AE60;
  color: white;
}

#msform .ms-field-title {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>

<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform">
  <!-- progressbar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
    <li>Social Profiles</li>
    <li>Personal Details</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset class="field-group">
    <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
    Labour:
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">£<span id="plaster"></span></h3><input hidden type="text" id="ouch" />
    <select name="cpu" id="CPU">
      <option value="0" selected>Width</option>
      <option value="10">2ft</option>
      <option value="20">4ft</option>
      <option value="30">6ft</option>
      <option value="40">8ft</option>
      <option value="50">10ft</option>
      <option value="60">12ft</option>
      <option value="70">14ft</option>
      <option value="80">16ft</option>
      <option value="90">18ft</option>
      <option value="100">20ft</option>
      <option value="110">22ft</option>
      <option value="120">24ft</option>
      <option value="130">26ft</option>
      <option value="140">28ft</option>
      <option value="150">30ft</option>
    </select>
    <select name="GPU" id="GPU">
      <option value="0" selected>Length</option>
      <option value="10">2ft</option>
      <option value="20">4ft</option>
      <option value="30">6ft</option>
      <option value="40">8ft</option>
      <option value="50">10ft</option>
      <option value="60">12ft</option>
      <option value="70">14ft</option>
      <option value="80">16ft</option>
      <option value="90">18ft</option>
      <option value="100">20ft</option>
      <option value="110">22ft</option>
      <option value="120">24ft</option>
      <option value="130">26ft</option>
      <option value="140">28ft</option>
      <option value="150">30ft</option>
    </select>
    <select name="bead" id="bead">
      <option value="0" selected>External Corners</option>
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="2.25">1</option>
      <option value="11.11">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <span style="text-align:left;" id="test" class="ms-field-title"><sup>*</sup></span>
    <button type="button" name="next" class="next is-disabled action-button" data-targetindex="1">Next</button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="field-group">
    <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
    <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
    <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
    <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
    <button type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" data-targetindex="0">Previous</button>
    <button type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" data-targetindex="2">Next</button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="field-group">
    <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
    <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
    <button type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" data-targetindex="1">Previous</button>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

found it i had to add

```
if (price === 24.60) {
        $("#plaster").html( 24.60 );
halt
      }
```